# how to make vimrc changes permanent on Neovim

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

I am new to nvim editor. i need help setting up my ~/.vimrc file. i have seen some tutorials and followed them. and came up with this:

```
> vim ~/.vimrc
```

have added this to my vimrc.

```
syntax on

set noerrorbells
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
set nu
```

and then source the file

```
:source %
```

the changes get applied instantly. but when i exit the file and open it again the changes disappear. if i source it again it works. is there any way i can make these changes permanent.
**[note] : when i exit the file i used `:x`**
**UPDATE:**
when i try to open `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` using vim. i am getting this error.

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/.local/share/nvim/swap//%home%manoj%.config%nvi
m%init.vim.swp"
          owned by: manoj   dated: Wed Mar 31 16:01:46 2021
         file name: ~manoj/.config/nvim/init.vim
          modified: YES
         user name: manoj   host name: manoj
        process ID: 15099
While opening file "/home/manoj/.config/nvim/init.vim"
      CANNOT BE FOUND
(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /home/manoj/.config/nvim/init
.vim"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/home/manoj/.local/share/nvim
/swap//%home%manoj%.config%nvim%init.vim.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "~/.local/share/nvim/swap//%home%manoj%.config%nvim%init.vim.swp" alre
ady exists!
```

Comment: `~/.vimrc` is Vim's main configuration file on Unix-like systems, which Neovim ignores because it has its own main configuration file. Read Neovim's documentation to know how that file is supposed to be named and where it is supposed to be. FWIW, don't assume anything you read about Neovim to be true for Vim and the other way around.

Comment: I suggest the title be: how to make vimrc changes permanent on Neovim

Comment: @romainl i tried to edit this file ```~/.config/nvim/init.vim``` but i am unable to please read the updated question.

Comment: Why don't you edit Neovim's main configuration file with Neovim? Also, the whole point of that message is to be *read* and *acted upon* by *you*. It is pretty explicit about the problem and about how to fix it.

Comment: This question should be modified. Although what @Manoj is asking is valid but the error mentioned in the question is completely unrelated to the question asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`~/.vimrc` is the default configuration file for vim. For neovim, simply copy the file to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` (You may need to create the nvim directory first).

Taken from the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Neovim#Configuration), although the most info is in the [official documentation](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki).

Comment: i have tried to edit this file ```~/.config/nvim/init.vim``` but i am not able to. i have updated it in the question please check.

Comment: I know just as much about that error as you do. Try rebooting, then create the directory (`mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim`) and the file (`touch ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`) manually.

Comment: everything working fine thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

in my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, there are the line :
`source ~/.vimrc`
I change it to :
`source ~/.vim/vimrc`
and neovim (v0.6.1) use my `~/.vim/vimrc` file settings

Comment: Re-use of existing file is very convenient! Note: if there are vim-only plugins/settings in  your `~/.vim/vimrc` or `~/.vimrc`, you can move the compatible settings into a `~/.vim/vimrc.common` and then source them from both your vim and nvim configurations.